# Bootstrap.min.css cdn not applying in JSP page

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp, netbeans

I have used html in Jsp to make login page. I have used Boostrap.min.css CDN and Font-awesome.min.css for styling in jsp page but css is not applying. IDE name- Netbeans 8.2 Spring MVC Project.
[Please have look on the image of jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzLJW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `resources` folder from `WEB-INF`. And put this folder under `Web Pages` folder. And in jsp page revome `..` in `<link href="">` and elements will exixts.

Comment: Ok, i will try this.

Comment: @PrinceRoshan Got your expected result ?